# How can I get the view function from an endpoint/rule?

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

In Flask(or werkzeug), how can I get the view function when all I have is the Rule? (or the Endpoint from that rule)?

Comment: Can you give an example of what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Werkzeug only stores a map of rules, each of which has an endpoint.  Flask adds to Werkzeug by associating each endpoint with a function.  Use the `app.view_functions` dict to get the view function from the endpoint name.

```
# assuming r is a Rule
f = app.view_functions[r.endpoint]
```