# Having the view function – how do I get the URL of a Blueprint route in Flask?

Tags: flask

The cache system I'm using ([Flask-Cache](https://github.com/thadeusb/flask-cache)) uses URLs to calculate cache keys. From a different place in the code I get passed a view function, and then need to check if the view has been cached.

Firstly, the current iteration of Flask-Cache needs the request to calculate the cache key, but I have made a [patch](https://github.com/SkierPGP/Flask-Cache/pull/1) that fixes the deficiency for simple cases, by getting the URL with `url_for(view_function.__name__, **kwargs)`.

The problem is that now I've started using [Flask Blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/blueprints/), and simply using `view_function.__name__` in `url_for` will not find the blueprint route (raises BuildError).

### Simple Flask app

```
@app.route('/user/<user_id>')
def user_page(user_id):
    return 'Hello user %s' % user_id

def check_cache(view_function, **kwargs):
    url = url_for(view_function.__name__, **kwargs)
    ... use URL to check cache ...

check_cache(user_page, user_id='123')
```

### Blueprint Flask app

```
from flask import Blueprint    

bp = Blueprint('user_blueprint', __name__)

@bp.route('/user/<user_id>')
def user_page(user_id):
    return 'Hello user %s' % user_id

def check_cache(view_function, **kwargs):
    url = url_for(view_function.__name__, **kwargs) # WON'T WORK WITH BLUEPRINTS
    ... use URL to check cache ...

check_cache(user_page, user_id='123')
```

How do I get the URL for the route/view function, when it's defined via a Blueprint?

Or alternatively, how do I make cache keys that will work when using blueprints? (And can be calculated via a decorator on a view function, and doesn't clash when two or more blueprints have view functions with the same name)

Comment: Maybe it's possible to go backward from `app.url_map` or `app.view_functions` but I don't see how? (reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32824414/118608)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `app.view_functions`

```
def check_cache(view_function, **kwargs):
    flipped_view_functions_dict = dict((v, k) for k, v in app.view_functions.iteritems())
    view_name = flipped_view_functions_dict[view_function]
    url = url_for(view_name, **kwargs)
    ... use URL to check cache ...
```

Comment: This is the correct solution. My next problem is that inside `Flask-Cache` the view function given won't necessarily reference the same function that's stored in `app.view_functions` in the case where there's a decorator between the route decorator and the cache decorator.

Answer (score 3):

Blueprints, by default, prepend the endpoint name with the blueprint name. In this way, the url_for string:

```
url = url_for('user_page')
```

Becomes:

```
url = url_for('user_blueprint.user_page')
```

Now, you are creating your url_for strings with the function name, so you can either switch to explicitly passing the endpoint strings as above, or use:

```
url = url_for('user_blueprint.' + view_function.__name__)
```

I don't know of a programmatic way to automatically find the blueprint name from the view_function.

Comment: The last line is exactly my problem: Inside Flask-Cache, I don't know which blueprint the view function belongs to. If `request` is available it seems that you can get the blueprint via `current_app.blueprints[request.blueprint]`, but in my use case `request` isn't available (reference: http://librelist.com/browser/flask/2012/4/7/current-blueprint/#44814417e8289f5f5bb9683d416ee1ee)

Comment: Why can't you switch to using the url_for strings directly? Then your check_cache would become check_cache(url_for_string, **kwargs): url = url_for(url_for_string) ...

Comment: Flask-Cache uses a decorator (usually invoked as `@app.cache.cached`) and thus only has the actual function available, not the name of the view/endpoint/route.